# Calculating Gray Level Co-occurrence Matrices (GLCM)

Tags: image-processing, grayscale, glcm

GLCM considers the relation between two pixels at a time, called the reference and the neighbour pixel. Based on the selection of the neighbour pixel generally 4 different Gray Level Co-occurrence Matrices (GLCM) can be calculated for an image.

Selection of the neighbour pixel is as follows.

```
reference pixel  |  neighbour pixel

(x,y)              (x+1, y)   the pixel to its right
(x,y)              (x+1, y+1) the pixel to its right and above
(x,y)              (x, y+1)   the pixel above
(x,y)              (x-1, y+1) the pixel to its left and above
```

A good, in-detail explanation about GLCM is available [here](https://www.ucalgary.ca/mhallbey/glcm1) ([Original link](http://www.fp.ucalgary.ca/mhallbey/the_glcm.htm)).

My question is, **is it required to consider all 3 intensity values of an image pixel when calculating Gray Level Co-occurrence Matrices (GLCM) of a *"gray scale image"***?

As an example consider an image with 2 pixels

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|               [pixel1]                 |                [pixel2]                 |
|            /      |     \              |             /      |     \              |
| [intensity1] [intensity2] [intensity3] | [intensity4] [intensity5] [intensity6]  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When calculating the GLCM of a gray scale image is it required to take into account all 3 intensity values of a pixel?

E.g- When the reference pixel is (x,y) and its neighbour pixel is (x+1, y) the pixel to its right

Is it required to take into account the occurrences of intensity levels individually as follows?

```
 [intensity1] & [intensity2]
 [intensity2] & [intensity3]
 [intensity3] & [intensity4]
 [intensity4] & [intensity5]
 [intensity5] & [intensity6]
```

Or can I just take into account one intensity value from each pixel, assuming all 3 intensity values of a pixel is same as follows?

```
[intensity1] & [intensity4]
```

Which is the correct method? Is it applicable for all 4 neighbours?

Comment: By definition the Red=Green=Blue intensity in a greyscale image, so just do any one.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the reply, wont the results vary under each method? which is the most recommended method?

Comment: It is my understanding that the point of using a greyscale image is to reduce the complexity by only needing to calculate for a single channel. I may be wrong - we shall see if anyone else knows better.

Comment: For a colour image, convert it to grayscale, then calculate the co-occurrence matrix.  That's if your image is colour.  If your image is purely grayscale, then using any channel is sufficient as all components in each channel are the same.